# scikit-learn "Working with Text Data Tutorial" ignores my target categories

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am working on ML algorithms and checked out: [Scikit-Learn Working with Text Tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Now I tried using my own training data set with 1 feature = message, and 5 categories rating from -2 (negative) to 2 (positive).

Then I do the same as stated in the tutorial, but it will always return a maximum of 4 target_categories and not 5!

```
target_categories = ['-2', '-1', '0', '1','2']

print(metrics.classification_report(train_data.Category, predicted,target_names=target_categories))
```

I will only get `predicted_proba` for -2,-1,0,1. for example: `[0.2 0.2 0.4 0.4]`

How come Scikit ist giving me only a 4x1 Vector and not 5x1? Why does the last value in my `target_categories` get omitted?

If I use only 3, I get an error:

```
values = [target_names[i]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: I think I found the problem, it seems to be that I used too few training datasets without one of the target_categories is inside.

Comment: If confirmed please put that comment as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the reason why it did not work was, because I split the training data at 50% and the `target_values` were not all included inside the training data. I will shuffle the data next time.